# Publishing error for single file .NET 5 project due to 3rd party dependencies

Tags: c#, .net-5, rawrabbit

Currently, on a `netcoreapp3.1` and I’m attempting to upgrade to `.net5`. There are no problems during compilation, but during runtime in Docker, I get:

> System.NotSupportedException: CodeBase is not supported on assemblies loaded from a single-file bundle.

I know that it's published [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/assembly-api-behavior-changes-for-single-file-publish):

> ### Recommended action
>
> Avoid dependencies on the file location of assemblies when publishing as a single file.

But I’m using [RawRabbit](https://github.com/pardahlman/RawRabbit) and it's gone inactive. I've also dug through the source and found just one place calling a deprecated [API](https://github.com/pardahlman/RawRabbit/blob/6229f5285d2cb5b9370ebfb616de2977d0386e24/src/RawRabbit/Common/ClientPropertyProvider.cs)

My current workaround is to not publish single file, but am I out of hope?

Comment: Any update? I had to uncheck the single file publish option also. I am not using RawRabbit but I believe what causing it for me is MySql.Data package.

Comment: You can follow this issue on GitHub https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/45543#issuecomment-751125789

Answer (score 12):

Set `IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract` to true in the publishing profile.

[image]